# Как обновить RSS ленту?

Tags: swift, xmlparser, rss

Вопрос, скорее всего, очень глупый, но не могу понять, в чем проблема.

**Что есть:** есть tableView, ячейки которого заполняются данными RSS из парсера (использую стандартный XMLParser)

**Что нужно:** чтобы в tableView при удерживании на refreshControl обновлялись ячейки с данными.

**Что сделано:** во viewDidLoad вызываю метод fetchData(), который отрабатывает. Этот же метод вызываю в action refreshControl, и он не отрабатывает.
Более того, было замечено, что метод fetchData() отрабатывает только один раз при установке приложения... как это можно поправить?

```
import UIKit

class MainViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    @IBOutlet weak var table: UITableView!
    private let url = "MY URL"
    private var rssItems: [RSSItem]? {
        didSet {
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.table.reloadData()
            }
        }
    }

    private var refreshControl: UIRefreshControl = {
        let refreshControl = UIRefreshControl()
        refreshControl.addTarget(self, action: #selector(refresh) , for: .valueChanged)
        return refreshControl
    }()

    @objc func refresh (sender: UIRefreshControl) {
        fetchData()
        sender.endRefreshing()


    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        table.addSubview(refreshControl)

       fetchData()


    }

    private func fetchData() {
        let feedParser = FeedParser()
        feedParser.parseFeed(url: url) { (rssItems) in
            self.rssItems = rssItems
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.table.reloadData()
            }
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

судя по коду, вы не вполне верно используете `UIRefreshControl`

объявляем

```
private let refreshControl = UIRefreshControl()
```

добавляем к таблице - это можно сделать например во `viewDidLoad()`

```
refreshControl.addTarget(self, action: #selector(refresh) , for: .valueChanged)
self.table.refreshControl = refreshControl
```

после этого должно заработать